# Slack static_select avoid backend call when change

Tags: slack-api

I have a slack modal with a static_select

```
{
      block_id: "my_block_id",
      type: "section",
      text: {
        type: "mrkdwn",
        text: "Please select one"
      },
      accessory: {
        type: "static_select",
        action_id: "select_type",
        placeholder: {
          type: "plain_text",
          text: "Select one"
        },
        options: self.types_options
      }
    },
```

When the user selects one of the option a backend call is been triggered, can I avoid that and have the call triggered on submit form button click?

Answer (score 6):

Put your `static_select` inside an [`input`](https://api.slack.com/reference/block-kit/blocks#input) rather than a `section`.

> When someone uses an interactive component in your app's modal views,
>   the app will receive a block_actions payload.
>
> This does not apply to components included in an input block (see
>   below for details about those).

https://api.slack.com/surfaces/modals/using#components

> Any interactive components used within input blocks will not send this block_actions payload. They are included in view_submission payloads only.

https://api.slack.com/reference/interaction-payloads/block-actions

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but not within a normal message.

Instead you want to use a [Modal](https://api.slack.com/surfaces/modals). Models are modal dialogs, which have a submit button and can have multiple input elements.

Comment: I have the inverse question: Is there a way to trigger the update when input value changes in a modal?